# JS creating divs with a for loop inside container

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, createelement

I am trying to create a number of divs inside a container, but i cant figure out how to nest the created ones within the main container. Is it also possible or better to create the container before in the html?

JS

```
function createDiv(numberOfDivs) {
  var i = 0;
  var newElement = [];
  var mainContainer = document.createElement('div');

  mainContainer.innerHTML = 'MAIN CONTAINER';
  mainContainer.className = 'main';
  document.body.appendChild(mainContainer);

  for (i; i < numberOfDivs; i++) {
    newElement[i] = document.createElement('div');
    newElement[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    newElement[i].className = 'box';
    newElement[i].id = (i + 1);
    newElement[i].textContent = 'this is div number: ' + (i + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(newElement[i]);
  }
};

createDiv(10);
```

Comment: You can create the container in html before and dont display them. Then you only need to add a class in js to make them visible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate 3000 squares procedurally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707643/generate-3000-squares-procedurally)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707643/generate-3000-squares-procedurally/40707772#40707772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create the container in the html ahead of time, as others have suggested.  Then you can nest your divs inside that container.

```
<html><body><div id="mainContainer" ></div></body></html>
```

As others suggested you can apply the necessary css to make it hidden if necessary until you want it visible.

Then javascript to nest divs inside mainContainer:

```
function createDiv(numberOfDivs){
    var $mainContainer = $("#mainContainer");
    for (i; i < numberOfDivs; i++) {
        var newDiv = $("<div class='box' />");

        //...you can add whatever attributes to the div that you want...

        $mainContainer.append(newDiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, just saw it but i tried to avoid jquery at all cost. but the append to main container helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help, the link to another topic helped i simply forgot to append the childs to the mainContainer.

```
function createDiv(numberOfDivs) {
  var i = 0;
  var newElement = [];
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById('main');

  for (i; i < numberOfDivs; i++) {
    newElement[i] = document.createElement('div');
    newElement[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    newElement[i].className = 'box';
    newElement[i].id = (i + 1);
//  newElement[i].textContent = 'this is div number: ' + (i + 1);
    mainContainer.appendChild(newElement[i]);
  }
};

createDiv(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should create them without using javascript.  Otherwise, you are appending the new elements to `document.body`.  Just change that to be `mainContainer`.

Comment: The new elements can be made outside of the DOM and then added all at once at the end.

Comment: How does that reflect on my comment about targeting the wrong element to append to?

Comment: It doesn't. But: *If you can, you should create them without using javascript.* is not correct.

Comment: If you know 100% of the time you are going to have some content on your page, static content, then yes you should.  Which is an opinion difference between us.

Comment: But the content isn't static as the OP has shown. The number of desired `div` elements will change. So, it's not static and, as such, should be done with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create them via Javascript (`.appendChild`) as well. If you want, you can create them in your HTML at first (without Javascript) and make them hidden if it's necessary via `display: none` for example, and then make them visible adding `display: block`.